# importing and exporting es6 classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I want to create ES6 class that reads data from a file and simply returns the content of the file, so I created a class called `FileReader` which has a constructor `filePath` and has a method called `getFileContent`

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

export class FileReader {

constructor(filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        this.fileContent = data;
    });
}

getFileContent(separator, columns) {
    console.log(this.fileContent);
}

}
```

I have a react component called `OrderList` I want to use `FileReader` inside `componentDidMount` method to read the content of the file

```
import React from 'react';
import {FileReader} from '../Utils/FileReader';

class OrdersList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader('');
        reader.getFileContent(',' , []);
    }


    render() {

    }
}


export default OrdersList;
```

the problem that I'm getting an error `Unexpected token reader` so what's wrong with this approach ?

Comment: This code has a conceptual design problem.  You attempt to read content in the constructor, but nobody outside the constructor ever has any idea when the content has finished reading and is actually valid for `getFileContent()`.  This simply will not work reliably (or perhaps at all) in practice.  The concept needs to be redesigned, probably using a promise so the caller of `getFileContent()` uses an async calling convention to know when the content is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this line: `FileReader reader = new FileReader('');` to `const reader = new FileReader('');`

Comment: seems to work perfectly, but could you please elaborate why it doesn't work in my case

Comment: @NaderHisham Because `FileReader reader` part makes no sense. If it's a variable, it should be declared with `var/let/const`.

Comment: and remember, make consts not vars :D

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You're reading file content in the constructor, in the most of the cases, `fileContent` will be undefined, because `fs.readFile` is async function.
2. You're creating a reader without file path: `FileReader reader = new FileReader('');`

To fix described problems you should move the logic for reading file in class function and use callback or promise:

```
class OrdersList extends React.Component {
  constructor(filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
 }

 getFileContent(separator, columns, cb) {
   fs.readFile(this.filePath, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      cb(err, data) ;
    });
  }
}
```

In OrdersList you should use real file name and call function with callback to read file content:

```
class OrdersList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let reader = new FileReader(realFilePath);
        reader.getFileContent(',' , [], (err, content) => {
          // TODO: file content in content var
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: but in this case we are not using `FileReader` class which we created in another file

Comment: why? you're creating it: `let reader = new FileReader(realFilePath);`, and using it method: `reader.getFileContent`